# How to broadcast message to all logged in users through Terminal?

Tags: software-recommendation, users, broadcasting

Is there a way of broadcasting a message to all logged in users through Terminal so that it is printed in the Terminals and TTYs of all other logged-in users? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `wall` command, it can be used as so:

```
echo "message" | wall
```

This will broadcast the message in Terminal to all logged in users through Terminal.